# TestNG pass command line arguments to testng.xml from java main method

Tags: java, testng, testng.xml

I am using parameters in my testng.xml file like this

```xml
<parameter name="name" value="value" />
```

But I want that parameter to get the value of a command line argument from my main method.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestNG runner = new TestNG();
    List<String> suitefiles = new ArrayList<String>();
    suitefiles.add(args[0]);
    runner.setTestSuites(suitefiles);
    runner.run();
}
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the parameters from the code using `@BeforeSuite` method along with `ITestContext` as an argument(which would be automatically injected by testng). No need to change the `main` method.

Before suite method would be run before any test method is executed.

```java
@BeforeSuite
public void beforeSuite(ITestContext ctx) {
    Map<String, String> paramMap = ctx.getSuite().getXmlSuite().getParameters();
    // put all parameters.
    map.put("name","value");
}
```

**EDIT:** When command line arguments to be used as parameters

```java
public class MyTest {
    // use this map to store the parsed params from command line.
    private static Map<String, String> paramMap = new HashMap<>();
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // parse args and put to paramMap
        paramMap.put(args[1],args[2]);
        TestNG runner = new TestNG();
        List<String> suitefiles = new ArrayList<String>();
        suitefiles.add(args[0]);
        runner.setTestSuites(suitefiles);
        runner.run();
    }
}
```

Now update the `beforeMethod` as:

```java
@BeforeSuite
public void beforeSuite(ITestContext ctx) {
    Map<String, String> paramMap = ctx.getSuite().getXmlSuite().getParameters();
    // put all parameters.
    map.putAll(paramMap);
}
```

Comment: I need it to be in Main class, since I need to use command line arguments. And @BeforeSuite does not run in that situation.

Comment: @mr_olaznog you can still use it with `beforesuite` i will update the answer

Comment: @mr_olaznog Hope the updated answer solves the issue.

Comment: `beforeSuite` method does not run.  It only runs when it is in one of the test classes.

Comment: @mr_olaznog you could make the map as `public` and access it using `MyTest.paramMap` from your beforeSuite if it is in a different test class